# prevent onchange event in jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using knockout with MVC in my project. when I pass viewModel on dropdown change It's getting continues ajax request to the server. How can I avoid the continues request??? any one can please help me on this???

My View

```
  @ko.Html.DropDownList(m => m.RoomList, new { @class = "full-width", @id = "rmch" }, "Text", "Value").Value(m=>m.NoOfRooms)
```

### Javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#rmch').on("change", function (e) {
                //viewModel.NoOfRooms = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("DropChange", "Home")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel),
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.redirect) {
                                location.href = resolveUrl(data.url);
                            }
                            else {
                                //ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("p_scentsFH"));

                                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);



                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert("There was an error posting the data to the server: " + error.responseText);
                        },
                    })

                });

            })
```

if I remove value part from the dropdownlist in the view It's working .but I need  the value for the processing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of is to set the dropdownlist to readonly before updating it, then when you have finished adding the new items, remove the readonly attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#rmch').on("change", function (e) {
                //viewModel.NoOfRooms = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("DropChange", "Home")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel),
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            //this will disable the onchange event
                            $('#rmch').attr("readonly","readonly");
                            if (data.redirect) {
                                location.href = resolveUrl(data.url);
                            }
                            else {
                                //ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("p_scentsFH"));

                                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);



                            }
                            //this will enable the onchange event for the next time you select something.
                            $('#rmch').removeAttr("readonly");

                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert("There was an error posting the data to the server: " + error.responseText);
                        },
                    })

                });

            })
```

Comment: I try this one. but still the same